I cant deploy my contract which I typed on 4.17 solidity in Remix-IDE
i tried to deploy my contract, however an error comes up
The Error: "creation of Inbox errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid params"
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Inbox {
    string public message;

    function Inbox(string initialMessage) public {
        message = initialMessage;
    } 
    function setMessage(string newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }

    function getMessage() public view returns (string) {
        return message;
    }

}


You need to supply the initial message argument ie.

I am using Remix above which may be helpful to you to test/develop since it does not let you even try to deploy when you are missing any args for creation: https://remix.ethereum.org/
